# Difference between this.variable and variable dart

Tags: flutter, oop, dart

I am confused by how dart handles its class variables.

Consider the below snippet.

```
  double income = 0.0;
  
  printer() {
    print(this.income);
    print(income);
  }
}

void main() {
  Testing testing = Testing();
  testing.printer();
}
```

Can someone enlighten me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually both prints 0. This is to refer to the class variable, if there is a name conflict.

> Use this only when there is a name conflict. Otherwise, Dart style omits the this.

Comment: Anhaa, name conflict between a variable in method and in class scopes right?